# Straight on orthogonal view turns to a transparent wireframe

Tags: 3d-view

When you go from perspective to a straight on orthogonal view, like the following video illustrates, is there a way for it to not turn into a transparent wireframe when it's in a straight on orthogonal view?
I'd like to keep [image] on, if possible.

video: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/aucg2qdc8dqijl9bv4b75/2023-09-27_22-29-01_Blender_blender.mp4?rlkey=soonzardy2vnqfpzj5q72r5js&dl=0

Comment: Hmmm... is it really turning into a wireframe or do you have any semi-transparent reference pictures that are set to only be visible in orthogonal view? And on the right I see a lot of things that seem to be coming from some kind of add-on, since I don't know what that is I have no idea if this could be causing the issue. Well, anyway: you have _Wireframe_ turned on in your screenshot, so another thing where without knowing your model I cannot tell if it is normal that these edges are visible.

Comment: Thanks @GordonBrinkmann, I adjusted my clip start and end, and it corrected it.  Not fully, but was pretty good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GordonBrinkmann, I adjusted my *Clip Start* and *Clip End*, and it corrected it. Not fully, but was pretty good enough.